# Need "Regular Expressions" that reject/require double occurrances of a parameter

Tags: regex

I've unfortunately been put in a position where I need to use "regular expressions". Problem is, I can't find any resource that explains how to use them in the basic language I can understand. The existing resources talk way over my head and lose me.

I'm using a 3rd party software that has an entry for regexes.  I'm not sure which regex engine it's actually using.

What I need is this:

One expression that will return results that begin with a specific string (e.g. "C:\Temp\Captures\"), end with one of several specific endings (e.g. ".exe", ".dll" or ".cab") - BUT DO NOT CONTAIN THOSE ENDINGS ANYWHERE IN THE MIDDLE OF THE RESULT!

e.g., for the list:

```
C:\Temp\Captures\One.dll.dll
C:\Temp\Captures\Two.exe
C:\Temp\Captures\Three.cab.howdy.exe
C:\Temp\Captures\Four.cab
C:\Temp\Captures\Five.dll
C:\Temp\Captures\Six.cab.cab
```

The expression would return results from all lines, but in the lines with text beyond the first .exe, .dll or .cab, it would lop of everything that comes afterwards and only return the text leading up to and including these first "ending" expressions.

In other words, it's results would be:

```
C:\Temp\Captures\One.dll
C:\Temp\Captures\Two.exe
C:\Temp\Captures\Three.cab
C:\Temp\Captures\Four.cab
C:\Temp\Captures\Five.dll
C:\Temp\Captures\Six.cab
```

The second expression I need is similar, except it must ONLY return lines that end with one of the approved endings (i.e. ".exe", ".dll", ".cab"), which occur after there has already been an occurrance of one of these endings.

In other words, out of the above list, it will only return the results:

```
C:\Temp\Captures\One.dll.dll
C:\Temp\Captures\Three.cab.howdy.exe
C:\Temp\Captures\Six.cab.cab
```

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what your target language is.  Not all regex is the same.

Comment: I have no idea. This is a 3rd party piece of software that seems to work off "regular expressions". I'd never heard of them before

Comment: Here is a good place to start: https://regex101.com/r/ckCzsj/1

Comment: Well we can't help you without your target language or dialect.  That's the *first thing* you should know.

Answer (score 1):

For your first list, you can use:

[`^.*?\.(?:cab|dll|exe)`](https://regex101.com/r/csS5jC/2)

Meaning beggining of a line (`^`) followed by anything, but as little as possible (`.*?`), followed by a dot (`\.`) and one of your extensions (`(?:cab|dll|exe)`).

And to retrieve the elements that have twice an extension, you can use :

[`^(?:.*\.(?:cab|dll|exe)){2,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/WayP1p/2)

Meaning a line containing ['anything' (`.*`) followed by a dot (`\.`) followed by one of your extention (`(?:cab|dll|exe)`)] at least twice (`{2,}`).

Provided your tool is compatible with PCRE regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions change based on target language and even version of target language, so, without knowing that, any expression we show you may not work correctly.

Nevertheless, here is an example that may work for your first request:

```
C:\\Temp\\Captures\\\S*?(?:(?:\.exe)|(?:\.cab)|(?:\.dll))
```